# Pandas equivalent of filter followed by groupby function in dplyr

Tags: python, r, pandas

There are 1000 rows and 50 columns in the data frame df. The following code in R's `dplyr` results in a tibble of 1000*50 and ID [1000] as there are 1000 distinct IDs in this df.

```
df1 = df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(row_number()==n())
```

I want to execute the same code in Pandas and the result should be a data frame. I got the groups with groupby command in Pandas:

```
df_groups = df.groupby(by=['ID'])
```

How to get `df1` after this step? After getting the `df1` the next step is to include one more column from another data frame.

Comment: kindly share sample data with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to do it with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), without learning pandas APIs:

```py
>>> from datar.datasets import mtcars
>>> from datar.all import f, group_by, row_number, n, filter
>>> mtcars >> group_by(f.cyl) >> filter(row_number() == n())
        mpg     cyl      disp      hp      drat        wt      qsec      vs      am    gear    carb
  <float64> <int64> <float64> <int64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64>
0      19.7       6     145.0     175      3.62      2.77      15.5       0       1       5       6
1      15.0       8     301.0     335      3.54      3.57      14.6       0       1       5       8
2      21.4       4     121.0     109      4.11      2.78      18.6       1       1       4       2

[Groups: cyl (n=3)]
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly the filter statement returns the last row in each group, in which case I believe you may be looking for:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID').last()
```